# QGIS get the X and Y of a raster file by click

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I have a raster file (Geotiff) and try to write a plugin that can change the value of one cell in a raster (== array cell).
I know how to get a QGIS point but how can I get the array index from on click on the canvas?

Answer (score 1):

You have to calculate these two values.

Georeferency is a tuple with 6 numbers: X coordinate of origin (upper left corner), horizontal resolution, rotation of X axis, Y coordinate, vertical resolution, rotation of Y axis.

You can use this pattern to calculate indexes:

```
COL = (X - OX) / RX
ROW = (Y - OY) / RY
```

X, Y are coordinates of pixel
OX, OY are coordinates of origin
Rx, RY are resolutions

COL is X index, ROW is Y index

With GDAL you can easily get those values, just open your data source (raster) and use:

```
georef = dataSource.GetGeoTransform()
```

Than you can get your values with indexes (order like above):

```
georef[0]
georef[3]
georef[1]
georef[5]
```